# Elasticsearch eat 100% of cpu

Tags: elasticsearch, devops

I have 3 node Elasticsearch cluster (7 verion) on this HW:

- vCPU: 8
- RAM 16 ( 8GB HEAP)
- disk SSD 300gb
- OS CentOS 7

So totally in my cluster I have 24 vCPU, 48 RAM, and 1,2 TB.
I have 70 indices (all of indices has 3 primary shards and 1 replica) and each index is about 25 GB.

This cluster used for storing logs from our services (EFK Stack) and we have Kibana and logtrail to visualize logs in web UI.

I have a CPU bottleneck:
Here's output from top command

```
PID    USER     PR  NI    VIRT    RES    SHR S  %CPU  %MEM    TIME+     COMMAND
15995 elastic+  20   0   92,2g  10,1g   1,3g S  640,0  64,9   269:27.70  java
```

So as you can see here, the Elasticsearch process ate all my CPU.

Output from `GET /_nodes/hot_threads`

```
curl 9.9.9.9:9200/_nodes/hot_threads
::: {10.0.87.160}{xPDGrNNmR962Mf51smGWQQ}{T6VTDspVSuujxVgi8KnuTg}{10.0.87.160}{10.0.87.160:9300}{dim}{xpack.installed=true}
   Hot threads at 2020-09-18T07:59:48.726Z, interval=500ms, busiestThreads=3, ignoreIdleThreads=true:
   100.2% (501.1ms out of 500ms) cpu usage by thread 'elasticsearch[10.0.87.160][search][T#1]'
     2/10 snapshots sharing following 43 elements
       app//org.apache.lucene.codecs.blocktree.IntersectTermsEnum._next(IntersectTermsEnum.java:510)
       app//org.apache.lucene.codecs.blocktree.IntersectTermsEnum.next(IntersectTermsEnum.java:353)
```

So as you can see here, the Search threads is hot, and eats 100% of CPU, but the Es slowlog file is empty so where is the problem?

Comment: I would take a stack trace (jstack) a few times, in case like this, when something is spinning hot it should give a solid lead.

Comment: I'd advise you to do some profiling. At first I was thinking on a general one, like Very Sleepy, but isn't there some tool, especially for ElasticSearch, for that?

Comment: Your slowlogs will be empty if you have a lot of quick queries. execution of workers  automated task  or heavy ingest pipelines can explain that kind of behavior. It can also be a good time for you to add specialized nodes, masters and or ingest depending on your use case